# Angular 2 and Node: Client and Server business logic convergence

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, architecture

We always need to perform validation and some business logic both in the server and client side. As we are using Angular2 and node with typescript (TS), we have conclude that a vast amount of the code and class model will be equal except by the persistence model (socket from client to server, sql from node to database).

As the objects can persist itself, we should be able to override just the save() method and so use codes like bellow

```
<input [ngModel]=‘person.getSomeProperty()’ (ngModelChange)=“person.setSomeProperty($event)“>
...
person.save()
```

person.save() would send the information to node that would rehydrate the class and perform the same person.save(), but by this time performing the dml into the database.

From this perspective, I have some question regarding the strategy:
* Is it sound reasonable to reuse code in such way? The uses cases do match.
* Is it correct to create a node module with all the business logic (like 20 classes) and export it to be used by the components?
* Can I two way bind to the same person.someMethod() from different components and views?

Comment: That really depends on what is your expectation. If it is API based and UI might be replaced later on, just keep your business logic in node.

Comment: If I try to create specific services to handle the business logic in the client, I will invariably re-create the logic we have already done.

Comment: I used to have a project which has the similar architecture you are proposing. However, it produces extra work on testing and maintenance. Both need double work. Hence, I really do not recommend this.